# Beginning of an nQueens game in c++. Where is the error located in my code?

Tags: c++

I keep getting errors when trying to compile the following code. The error is

`expected ',' or ';' before '{' token.`

It says there's an error on the parentheses after the `bool check_row(x)`
If I comment it out the same happens for `bool check_col(x)`.
I kept looking back at my books if I didn't define my functions properly but they seem correct, logically.
This is the beginning of an nQueens game on a 4x4 board.
The Queen is represented by the number 1.
The two boolean functions are to check if the row and columns are free.
`startGame()` assigns 0 to all boxes, and `showBoard()` shows results of the board.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int x=0, y=0;
int square[4][4];

void startGame()
{
    for(x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<4;y++)
        {
            square[x][y]=0;
        }
    }
}
void showBoard()
{
    for(int x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
        if(x!=0)
        {
            cout<<endl;
        }
        for(int y=0;y<4;y++)
        {
            cout<<square[x][y];
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
bool check_row(x)
{
    for(y=0;y<4;y++)
    {
        if(square[x][y]==1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(square[x][y]==0)
        {
            if(y==3)
            {
                return true;
            }
            continue;
        }
    }
}
bool check_col(y)
{
    for(int x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
        if(square[x][y]==1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(square[x][y]==0)
        {
            if(x==3)
            {
                return true;
            }
            continue;
        }
    }
}
int main(){

    startGame();
    showBoard();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to specify the `datatype` which you are passing as a `parameter` in your function..considering `x` and `y` are of `int` type and are `local`, your `function prototype` should be

```
bool check_row(int x)
bool check_col(int y)
```

If `x` and `y` are `global` then there is no need to pass them..simply

```
bool check_row()
bool check_col()
```

will work as the `visibility` of `global variables` will be *throughout the program, unless shadowed*

Answer (score 2):

`bool check_col(y)` isn't a valid prototype. You need to provide a type for `y` - for example `bool check_col(int y)`. The same applies to `bool check_row(x)`.

Comment: I assumed you meant to pass them in. If you just meant to use the global variables, then there is no need to mention `x` or `y` in the function signature. Since they are present in the global scope, they will be visible inside your functions. In general, any variable in a scope is visible to all variables within scopes nested inside it, as long as it isn't shadowed by a variable with more inner scope. For example, `x` in `showBoard`'s `for` loop refers to the variable local to the `for` loop. However, outside this loop, `x` refers to the global variable `x`.